# directory traversal encoding CAPEC \x4F

Tags: directory-traversal

I want to ask about something called `CAPEC \x4F`, I know it has something to do with directory traversal characters' encoding, but I dont know anything else about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAPEC is the "Common Attack Pattern Enumeration and Classification". `\x4F` is hexadecimal for `79`.

[CAPEC-79: Using Slashes in Alternate Encoding](https://capec.mitre.org/data/definitions/79.html) is about encoding the slash character to bypass filters that should filter for directory traversal.

Comment: can you give me an example of slash character encoding please?, because I am trying to try a directory listing vulnerability on a wargame site, but that site has filtered the common methods to do the directory traversal thing

Comment: Also how did you know that `\x4F` is hexadecimal for `79`, I was using an converter from hex to text but it shows me the value `O`

Comment: @adib The linked article names a couple of examples, eg using \ instead of /, URL encoding, utf8 encoding, etc. and `\x` just denotes that the following is hexadecimal (so you don't eg confuse `\x11` with `11` (decimal), and `4F (hex)` is `79 (dec)`.

Comment: I have tried it, It doesn't work. It gives me an error saying `Invalid url`. But when I try `%2F..%2F..%2Ftrojan_robot.txt` it says `permission denied`